# How product collection works

Tags: php, magento

I currently don't have a means to test this bit of code unfortunately, but wanted to ask the community what the outcome would be and the order of operations performed behind the scene. It's a short PHP code that shuffles and loads (not sure of the operation order) products for the front-end. (A and B are labels for reference in this post)

```
A. $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC');

B. if ($sortType == 'shuffle') {
    $productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
}
```

**My question** is, will this set up the `SELECT` query at `A.` and append the order randomization to the query string in `B.` and run the query in `B.`, resulting in the same 10 products being loaded in random orders?

The reason I'm asking is that, in the below (simplified) code that is running on our site, it always loads 10 different items in random order. From looking at the order in which the code is run, it seems to me as I've described above. Note that `$productCollection` after this can be iterated as the items are loaded already. If `D.` is omitted, then it just gets the 10 newest products/entity_ids.

*It's not clear to me* how `C.` by itself loads products, but `D.` can retrospectively change what's already loaded.

```
C. $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 3)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('gteq' => $date));

D.     if ($sortType == 'shuffle') {
    $productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random order clause has to be set on the collection object first. However, unless I'm mistaken, your conditions A and B are exclusive when used together. Perhaps using an either/or approach would work?

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->setPageSize(10);

if ($sortType == 'shuffle') {
    $productCollection->getSelect()->orderRand(); //wrapper; entity_id is implicit
} else {
    $productCollection->setOrder('entity_id'); //desc is default
}
```

If the two calls are disparate, and the `entity_id` field is being added as the first `order` column, it would be necessary to reset the `order` part of the select object before setting the random order, in which case your part B would look like the following:

```
if ($sortType == 'shuffle') {
    $productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $productCollection->getSelect()->orderRand();
}
```

***Edit - I've reread your question, and I have the following to add**: The parts of the query (e.g. order clause) and more importantly the query results are not available until the collection object is loaded implicitly or explicitly. You could do something similar to the following:*

```
$items = $productCollection->getItems();
shuffle($items);
```

*And work with the $items array thereafter.*

***Subsequent edit - responding to OP edit***

Regarding `C.` & `D.` - Collection classes do not `load()` anything until they need to. There is no code in `C.` or `D.` which will trigger this. Any of the following, however, will trigger the query, retrieval of results, and model instance assignment:

```
count($productCollection);
foreach($productCollection as $product){/*...*/};
$productCollection->getColumnValues();
$productCollection->getFirstItem();
$productCollection->getItemByColumnValue();
$productCollection->getItems();
$productCollection->getItemsByColumnValue();
$productCollection->getIterator();
$productCollection->getLastItem();
$productCollection->getSize();
$productCollection->load();
$productCollection->loadData();
```

*NB - The first two are side effects of collection classes inheriting the `IteratorAggregate` and `Countable` interface from `Varien_Data_Collection`.*

FYI, once the collection class has `load()`ed, it has to be `clear()`ed in order to re-issue a query.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the reply. We have a piece of code similar to this running on our site, and it doesn't to the `getItems()`, but products are available as request above. I'm going to update my post with a simplified version of what's running and what it's returning.